# Extracting Usermade Properties From an Image metadata Python

Tags: python, image, extract, metadata

How can I extract **custom usermade properties** from an image metadata in Python?

This is my current code that uses piexif library:

```
import piexif

image_name = 'D1241-118.jpg'
exif_dict = piexif.load(image_name)

thumbnail = exif_dict.pop('thumbnail')
if thumbnail is not None:
    with open('thumbnail.jpg', 'wb') as f:
        f.write(thumbnail)

print(f'Metadata for {image_name}:')
for ifd in exif_dict:
    print(f'{ifd}:')
    for tag in exif_dict[ifd]:
        tag_name = piexif.TAGS[ifd][tag]["name"]
        tag_value = exif_dict[ifd][tag]
        print(f'\t{tag_name:25}: {tag_value}')
print()
```

I have this image, and I would like to get the "Keywords" metadata from it:
[image](https://gpophotoheb.gov.il/fotoweb/cmdrequest/rest/Download.fwx/D1217-072.JPG?D=C81D6356E1BFEA156E1871B36C2AB119898895604DC1D2ADB599A2E66BBB14531CC84BC505428176FD39000DC9A02C4F4625D291663D8FC24862086D6FB61F3F8E994C660459D1907780F0C0C67660E6943A594F15C0DAF54C6A81E1127C86E6810654CD1070787AE05A5B36E8395F2E4E8F58F31E22F552&ForceSaveDialog=yes)

This is a screenshot that shows the wanted metadata:
[image: screenshot]

I tried every single library/solution and nothing works.

All the solutions gives me the same output, it gives me all metadata keys & values **besides** the one I need.

Comment: By posting your image through imgur, you likely stripped it of the relevant metadata - the image you shared doesn't appear to have any. Why do you think the image has 'Keywords' metadata? What tool have you used to come to that conclusion? Is it indeed EXIF metadata? What output did you get, and what output did you expect?

Comment: Hey, thank you for the quick reply, I have edited the post and shared a screenshot with the wanted metadata.

When I download the image from the link I shared - I am able see the metadata.

Comment: If the answer below is not the answer you require, please comment on what additional problems need solving.

Answer (score 2):

The keywords you are after are not part of the EXIF data, but instead have been embedded as IPTC info data.

If you install a third party package like IPTCInfo3:

```
pip install iptcinfo3
```

This will work:

```
from iptcinfo3 import IPTCInfo

image_name = 'D1217-072.jpg'
info = IPTCInfo(image_name)
print(info['keywords'])
```

For the image you provided a link to, the output looks like this:

```
[b'\xe7\xe9\xe8\xe4', b'\xf9\xe3\xe4', b'\xe8\xe1\xf2', b'Wheat', b'Nature', b'Field', b'Crop', b'Crops', b'\xfa\xe1\xe5\xe0\xe4']
```

Edit: out of curiosity, I noted that the byte encoding was not UTF-8. It looks like you need something like this to correctly decode the Hebrew:

```
print(list(map(lambda x: x.decode('iso8859-8'), info['keywords'])))
```

Output:

```
['חיטה', 'שדה', 'טבע', 'Wheat', 'Nature', 'Field', 'Crop', 'Crops', 'תבואה']
```

That is, the encoding of the keywords is in ISO 8859-8.

Comment: You're welcome - if this answered your question, please consider clicking the check mark next to it. This will mark your question as answered, so that it no longer shows up for people looking for questions to answer. And people looking for answers will know that an answer can be expected here.